# how to copy selected items from listview to textarea by drag and drop

Tags: listview, javafx, drag-and-drop, textarea, items

Something is wrong in my simple application. I tried to copy selected items from listview to textarea by drag and drop, but I guess I did make a fault with the handling of 'drag detected'.
No text is dropped. When dragging text from an editor it is dropped in the textarea.

Thanks for your help!

This is the code.

```
public class Main extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea("my textarea\n");
    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Julia", "Ian", "Sue", "Matthew", "Hannah", "Stephan", "Denise"));
    listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    listView.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    listView.setPrefHeight(50.0);

    textArea.setOnDragOver(dragEvent -> {
        if (dragEvent.getDragboard().hasString()) dragEvent.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY);
        dragEvent.consume();
    });

    textArea.setOnDragDropped(dragEvent -> {
        Dragboard db = dragEvent.getDragboard();
        boolean success = false;
        if (db.hasString()) {
            textArea.appendText(db.getString());
            success = true;
        }
        dragEvent.setDropCompleted(success);
        dragEvent.consume();
    });

    listView.setOnDragDetected(dragEvent -> {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("my selection: ");
        Dragboard dragboard = listView.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.COPY);
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().forEach(item -> {
            sb.append("\t");
            sb.append(item);
        });
        content.putString(sb.toString());
        dragboard.setContent(content);
        if (dragboard.hasContent(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT)) System.out.println(content);
        dragEvent.consume();
    });
    borderPane.setTop(listView);
    borderPane.setCenter(textArea);

    Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 500, 250);
    stage.setTitle("Drag & Drop");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

}

---

@Slaw, thanks for your comment. Now I have tested the application at Ubuntu and Windows10.

Ubuntu

```
     java -version
     openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14
     OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
     OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Windows10

```
    java -version
    openjdk version "12.0.2" 2019-07-16
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The code works with Windows10, but not with Ubuntu. Therefore I think it's correct. But I don't know where I can find the cause for the problem at Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you calling all of the appropriate drag and/or drop events?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/HelloDragAndDrop.java.html

Comment: No, I handle only 'drag over' an 'drag dropped' as I think the other are not necessary

Comment: Your code works for me (JavaFX 14.0.1, Java 14, Windows 10).

Comment: [JDK-8240293](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8240293) shows there are issues with Linux and drag-and-drop. However, the comments indicate this should be fixed in JavaFX 14. Try using the latest version of JavaFX (i.e. 14.0.1) if you're not already.